# Using Solspace Calendar, repeating events with with a start dates over a year old don't show up, if when "Until" field is set to far in the future

Tags: solspace-calendar

Here is the search we're using in the template.

```
{exp:calendar:events
    date_range_start="today"
    date_range_end="today"
    calendar="1"}

{/exp:calendar:events}
```

The events we are looking for have a start/end date in the past but are set to repeat until a certain date (usually in year 2048).

It works fine if the event's start date is less than 1 year old.  As soon as it's older than 1 year, the even won't show up, even if the Until field is set to 2048.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this becomes a bit of a limitation with Calendar for performance reasons. Calendar needs to check for all occurrences across a specific timeframe, and the larger that timeframe is, the heavier the request is - especially for sites with many events. It seems like this has worked well for most customers, but I understand it will affect some others.

The current limitation is 365 recurrences of a single event (allowing for a daily event to happen for 1 full year).

If you have an event that occurs quite frequently, it's more likely you'll run into this issue. It can be worked around by bumping up the start date every once in a while, or make new copies of the event for each calendar year, etc.